# Why can't my computer connect to this one valid website?

Tags: windows, networking, google-chrome, dns

I am trying to visit the website  https://www.khronos.org/ on my Windows 10 machine.

This website is currently up. It works on my computer at work and on my phone at home. However, it does not work on my computer at home.

To deal with this issue, I [switched to using Google's DNS](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7406/speed-up-your-web-browsing-with-google-public-dns/). After switching I tried `ipconfig /flushdns` and rebooted my computer. It still doesn't work.

I used a third part NS lookup server and saw that the domain resolves to the IP address: `104.236.24.254`. I tried using that IP directly and it still does not work.

I check and no edits have been made to my windows `hosts` file.

Running `tracert` returns `Unable to resolve target system name https://www.khronos.org/` (with and without the slash).

This fails on every browser I tried and I can not ping the URL nor the IP address.

I do not have any antivirus software installed and Windows firewall is turned off.

Any ideas?

Comment: could your antivirus or anti malware programs be blocking it? Not suggesting it is a dodgy site, just that these programs have the ability to block access if they wish.

Comment: What is the output of `tracert https://www.khronos.org/`? what about `tracert 104.236.24.254`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski `Unable to resolve target system name https://www.khronos.org/` same without trailing slash.

Comment: @SirAdelaide Good point. I odn't see any antivirus installed and have my firewall turned off.

Comment: Maybe your ISP banned this site/IP. Try access it via another internet connection or a VPN service.